# E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory with gradle:3.6.0

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I'm working on a project and updated my Gradle from 3.5.3 to 3.6.0 and then got this error:

```
020-02-24 21:52:34.255 16943-16943/net.chattag.chattag W/chattag.chatta: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/net.chattag.chattag-Zlw1vfGHfVAGo6rU-RKDNg==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
2020-02-24 21:52:34.258 16943-16943/net.chattag.chattag E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.chattag.chattag-Zlw1vfGHfVAGo6rU-RKDNg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/net.chattag.chattag-Zlw1vfGHfVAGo6rU-RKDNg==/lib/x86, /data/app/net.chattag.chattag-Zlw1vfGHfVAGo6rU-RKDNg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:256)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:855)
```

I try to add set Java source compatibility to 1.8 via my Gradle build file

```
compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
```

But this does not work.

Comment: - Fix language and punctuation
- Remove irrelevant details
- Some formatting fixes
- Describe the Java compat change more clearly

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: yes, i forgot to att this lines: apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' in build.gradle(:app) i added kotlin to my project and this was the fault. sorry for bad english.